# In R calculate fibonnaci using dynamic programing

Tags: r, recursion, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I tried to write a function to calculate the nth Fibonnaci number in R. I can do this recursively.

```
fibonacci = function(n){
  if (n == 1) {return(1)}
  if (n == 2) {return(2)}

  return(fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2))
}
```

I couldn't find any examples in R but from guide in other languages I came up with the following. However it doesn't seem to run any faster.

```
fibonacci = function(n, lookup = NULL){
  if (is.null(lookup)) {
    lookup = integer(n + 1)
  }


  if (n == 1) {return(1)}
  if (n == 2) {return(2)}

  lookup[1] = 1
  lookup[2] = 2

  if (lookup[n - 1] == 0) {
    lookup[n - 1] = fibonacci(n - 1, lookup)
  }

  if (lookup[n - 2] == 0) {
    lookup[n - 2] = fibonacci(n - 2, lookup)
  }
  return(lookup[n - 1] + lookup[n - 2])
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? Is this just about speed? What timings did you do to test your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that your lookup vector is always local to the call frame environment and new solutions are not propagated up to the callers, i.e., changes to the lookup vector are lost when the function returns. In order to make a persistent variable a la static variables in C, you may create an attribute to the function that acts as a memoizer. Here is one solution:

```
fibonaccid = function(n, init=T){
  if (init) {
    lookup <- integer(n + 1)
    lookup[1] <- 1
    lookup[2] <- 2
  } else {
    lookup <- attr(fibonaccid, ".lookup")
  }

  # ... calculate lookup as before, recurse with fibonaccid(...,init=F)

  attr(fibonaccid, ".lookup") <<- lookup

  return(lookup[n - 1] + lookup[n - 2])
}
```

This indeed runs much faster:

```
R> system.time(print(fibonacci(35)))
[1] 14930352
   user  system elapsed
  20.923  0.140  21.446

R> system.time(print(fibonaccid(35)))
[1] 14930352
   user  system elapsed
  0.202   0.006   0.209
```

See [this post](https://medium.com/@hshihab/emulating-c-like-static-variables-in-r-c3cde0334f1b) for more information.